# Looping through a list of dataframes to create different plots

Tags: pandas, for-loop, plot

I have a list of dataframes:

```
list=[mean_ave,rmse_ave,bias_ave,
                std_ave,std_diff_ave,trend_ave,trend_diff_ave,
                corr_mean,ano_rmsd]
```

For each of those dataframes I would like to produce a heatmap as shown in the example below.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 12))
sns.heatmap(mean_ave, cmap='RdBu', 
            annot=True, 
            fmt='.2f')
```

I was thinking of looping through the list but I am quite inexperienced.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### The key is to add the ax parameter in the heatmap

```
for idx, df in enumerate(list):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(len(df),1 , figsize=(8, 12))
    sns.heatmap(df, cmap='RdBu', 
                annot=True, 
                fmt='.2f', ax=ax[idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

One remark, first: `list` is not the best choice of name, use df_list or dfs, for instance (or any other name less ambiguous).

You could try this:

```
f, axs = plt.subplots(len(df_list), 1, figsize=(8, 12))
for i, df in enumerate(list_df):
    sns.heatmap(
    df,
    cmap='RdBu', 
    annot=True, 
    fmt='.2f',
    ax=axs[i])
```

Comment: Thanks.  This loop gives me a `SyntaxError` (positional argument follows keyword argument)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that "mean_ave" argument, try without it and less keywords (I modified my answer accordingly).

Comment: Now it gives an `IndexError` (too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed). Sorry, for troubling you!

Comment: No pb. Try with axs[i] instead of axs[i, 1]